# Find All Users By Last Login Time

Tags: sql

We have two tables:

```
USERS
-id
-name
```

---

```
USER_LOGINS
-user_id
-login_date
```

How to find users and their last login time:
User_name: last_login_date

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM USER_LOGINS
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY login_date DESC;

Comment: This is pretty basic SQL. Any tutorial on SQL should cover what you need to work this out. You should really have researched a little before posting your question, and posted what you have tried and where you are struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following query

```
select u.name, max(l.login_date)
from USERS u
inner join USER_LOGINS l on u.id = l.user_id
group by u.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, Max(login_date)
FROM USER_LOGINS 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join users and user_logins to get the name and login date. You then need to use the `MAX` function to get the last login date. When you perform aggregation (e.g. using `MAX`) you need to `GROUP BY` on non-aggregated fields.

```
SELECT u.name AS User_Name, MAX(ul.login_date) AS Last_Login_Date
FROM Users u
   JOIN User_Logins ul ON u.id = ul.user_id
GROUP BY u.name
```